Can Laham mages learn Demon Lores?
On Page 80 of Book of Secrets, there is the Nephilim/Laham merit. It mentions providing several infernal investments if you opt to be a Laham. While it makes no mention of providing access to Demon Lores from Demon: the Fallen, it looks like it is a minor splat similar to ghoul or kinain. In summary, can a Mage with the Laham merit spend experience to learn Demon Lores?

Lore (X) is an available skill...
...if you can find a source to learn from. The "Lore" Knowledge is one of the many, many secondary knowledge abilities you might have, and is detailed in the core book:1

Different Lore categories include: Spirits, Fae, Werecreatures,
Vampires, Ghosts, Hunters, Demons, Mages (naturally…), and
potentially others as well. Each Lore/ RD Data category counts
as a separate Lore specialty; knowing about Sabbat Kindred won’t
teach you anything about Seelie Fae Kith. The Well-Skilled
Craftsman option may help you assemble a formidable amount
of information about various groups within those categories.
Even then, however, your knowledge will be full of holes,
misconceptions, prejudices, and lies. These secretive beings
don’t even have accurate appraisals of themselves, so an outsider
(especially a Technocratic one) has obvious disadvantages in
that regard as well.
[...] Suggested Specialties: Infernalists, Marauders, Traditions,
Technocracy, Disparates, Faeries, Vampires, Werebeasts, Ghosts,
Hunters, Demons, etc.

This is one of the cases of mandatory specialization, akin to Crafts. The rules suggest that one might use the "well-skilled Craftsman" rules, as they do for Arts and Crafts.2
The other option is that the Storyteller chooses that this rule does not apply, and thus you'd need to learn separate Lore abilities for Lore (Demons) and Lore (Technocracy).
There's also an option to even apply those, which would be my preferred choice, and has successfully been used in games for years. For more on that, see below.
Justifying your Lore (X)
Being a Laham could convince your Storyteller to allow you to take Lore (Demons) at Character Generation, while it would require actual effort to raise the ability in the game, such as either managing to either find a source to learn from - usually a specimen of the thing you research acting as a tutor or a book on the topic - or otherwise obtain a source to conduct your own research. That could be monitoring a specimen in the wild, prodding a captive one, or even other, less savory, options that don't even stop with the demise of the specimen. The Progenitors are particularly fond of the last two options.
My suggested ruling
If I were your Storyteller, I would insist on separate knowledge abilities per topic. Lore Demon after all has little to no overlap with Lore Fae or Lore Vampires. However, I'd also allow to specialize at 4 within your ability, such as Lore Vampire (Sabbat) or Lore Technocracy (Progenitors), and apply the well skilled craftsman rules upon those extra specialties.
You CAN'T learn Demon powers
Demon Powers require that you are a fallen angel, are powered by Faith and Torment has all the other benefits of being a Demon. You can not get those as a Mage, or any other splat. Being a Demon is exclusive with any other splat: you either are a soul that was tormented in the Abyss and then found a vessel to possess, or you are not. You need to realize what Faith is:

Faith
Faith is the core of the fallen’s power, the ability
that once let them literally move mountains. Although
their power is no longer what it was, demons can still
influence Creation in various ways through their Faith.
Faith is a combination of a demon’s self-assurance,
insight into the nature of Creation and closeness to the
divine power they once wielded. Before the Fall, demons
had faith in their Creator and drew their power from
Him. Now the fallen place their faith only in themselves
(and sometimes in humanity) and draw their power from
their belief in themselves and mortals’ faith in them.3

Also, Demons are very much only possessing people that are utterly broken - which is quite the opposite of what a mage stands for:

To survive [after the host dies], the demon must find a new host. Yet doing so is difficult because the same restrictions apply that
were imposed on the demon when it escaped from Hell.
It must possess a living body, one whose mind or soul is so
diminished that they are barely human.4

On the other side, you either have an Avatar, or you do not. Note that getting embraced (aka, turning Vampire) removes your Avatar. Full Werewolves can't be mages, they are already Spirits, so an Avatar can't attach. There's only two options for mages to cross into other Splats:

Drinking Vitae, which is very dangerous, addictive and can damage your Avatar
Be related to a Werebeing, making you kinfolk, but you can't gain the merits to gain Gnosis, you don't get anything but being related to one, and probably not getting sliced to bits. They won't let you into the Caern, Wordbreaker.


1 - Mage 20, p.299.
2 - Mage 20: Optional Rule: The Well-Skilled Craftsman, p.279.
3 - Demon the Fallen, p.159.
4 - Demon the Fallen, p.259.

You're mistaken about the subject of the question. In Demon: The Fallen, "Lores" are the supernatural powers that Fallen have, akin to Disciplines or Arcanoi. https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Lore_(DTF)

@Jadasc oh? Well, you can't do that. Quick fix, looking up where exactly that was written, but I am very sure it was.

I believe that the vitae drinking damaging your avatar was mentioned in blood treachery and removed in M20 turning Ghoul into a five dot merit. Likewise there is a merit called kinfolk gnosis which gives a kinfolk...well gnosis.

@MaikoChikyu "vitae drinking damaging your avatar was... removed in M20" IIRC it's mentioned that ghoul Mages are incapable of increasing their Gnosis?

Probably not, but you can use your Spheres to pretend.
The Merit doesn't say you do, so you probably don't, no. It's honestly pretty strong as it is, anyway, with the constant source of free Quintessence.
However, in the Book of Secrets, one of the potential options for a Mage's Paradigm cam be summed up as "I can do stuff ordinary humans can't because I'm not an ordinary human". Being part-demon would give a Mage with a Paradigm like that an obvious justification to use their Magick to duplicate Demon powers, much like being a cyborg would justify using high-tech cyborg powers or being a vampire-derived Construct would justify you using Magick to mimic vampire powers.
